# Trouble returning date from DatePickerDialog fragment when using Navigation Controller

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to return a date selected from my DatePickerDialog. I know there are a few questions about this here on SO and I am sure I have checked for those in my code and I still can't get the date back into my fragment that calls the DatePickerDialog.

I am using the Navigation confonent to show the dialog, could that be what is causing the issue?

Here is my DatePickerDialog:

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private var onDateSetListener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener? = null

    fun setListeningActivity(listener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) {
        onDateSetListener = listener
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        onDateSetListener?.onDateSet(view,year, month, dayOfMonth)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return DatePickerDialog(context, this, year, month, day)
    }
}
```

Relevant code from the fragment calling the Datepicker:

```
private fun showDatePicker(hasFocus: Boolean, view: View) {
    Log.i(FRAGMENT_NAME, "Has focus $hasFocus")
    val fragment = DatePickerFragment()
    fragment.setListeningActivity(this)
    if (hasFocus) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.datePickerFragment)
    }
}

override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    Log.i(FRAGMENT_NAME, "Date received: $year-$month-$day")
    fragmentView.dateOfBirthField.editText?.setText("$year-$month-$day")
}
```

This is how I am calling the showDatePicker method:

> fragmentView.dateOfBirthField.editText?.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus -> showDatePicker(hasFocus, fragmentView) }

Question: How do I get the date back into the Fragment that calls the DatePickerDialog. I do not want to have the DatePickerDialog as an internal class to the class that calls it.

Comment: I would suggest to use `livedata` with `ViewModel`.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way for fragment data passing is `livedata` with `viewmodel`, when you are using navigation architecture component.

**Step-1** Create `ViewModel` which will hold your `selectedDate`. Create the instance of `LiveData` so that you can observe the changes.

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val selectedDate: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

**Step-2** Get the instance of `SharedViewModel` and update `selectedDate` variable to notify it's observers. (In `DatePickerFragment`)

```
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
    viewModel.selectedDate.value = "$year $month $day"
}
```

**Step-3** Get the instance of `SharedViewModel` where, you want to observe the changes. (In our case, from where `datePickerFragment` invoked.)

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
            .selectedDate
            .observe(activity!!, Observer { dateOfBirthField.editText.setText(it) })
}
```

If you are using `androidx` artifact. Then you may need follwoing dependency.

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha01'
```

Comment: Hey man, sorry for not getting back to this sooner. This worked perfectly, thanks for the detailed explanation and the sample code.  Just a quick question, why would a standard listener not work when using the navigation controller?

Comment: I am not sure. But I guess, It didn&#39;t work because instance of fragment is created by navcontroller. So In that case we don&#39;t have correct reference in the original fragment.

Comment: Yeh, sorry about that. Is there some way I can send you the 50 points?

Comment: No problem bro, you got the solution that's more important.

Answer (score 0):

One can either set a target `Fragment`:

```
val fragment = DatePickerFragment()
fragment.setTargetFragment(this, requestCode)
```

or let it deliver the result to an `Activity`:

```
val fragment = DatePickerFragment()
fragment.setListeningActivity(this)
```

this should happen before showing the `DialogFragment`; so that the `DialogFragment` will already know where it has to deliver it's result to. For either delivery destination, method `onDateSet()` needs to return an `Intent` with an extras `Bundle`... and [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity.html#onActivityResult(int,%2520int,%2520android.content.Intent)) needs to process that result and update the GUI accordingly. This is how the communication in between `Activity` & `Fragment` works - and this also applies to a `DialogFragment`. Method `onActivityResult()` may handle the callbacks from both, `Activity` and `Fragment`.

In Java that would be something alike this - for returning the result in the `DialogFragment`, in method `override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int)`:

```
/* converting the selection to long integer */
GregorianCalendar date = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
date.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, year);
date.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, month);
date.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "confirmed " + date.getTime());
long dueDate = date.getTime().getTime();

if (getTargetFragment() != null) {

    /* stuffing the result value into a Bundle */
    Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putLong(ArgumentKeys.ARGUMENT_SELECT_DUE_DATE, dueDate);
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    /* this delivers the result */
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    /* close dialog */
    this.dismiss();

} else {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, ".setTargetFragment() had not been called.");
}
```

or similarly for returning to an `Activity`:

```
if(this.dialog.getOwnerActivity() != null) {
    ...
}
```

and the `onActivityResult()` of the `Activity` or `Fragment` which opened the `DialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCodes.REQUESTCODE_TASK_DUE_DATE: {
                if(extras != null) {
                    long dueDate = extras.getLong(ArgumentKeys.ARGUMENT_SELECT_DUE_DATE, -1);

                        /* set the value in here */
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
    }
}
```

returning a `Fragment` result works almost alike returning an `Activity` result.